# Chi-Square Test Problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

[image]a. 56 cells (87.5%) have expected count less than 5. The minimum expected count is .02.

Df: 49
P Value: .049

Is this result significant or I may select any other test?. Please guide me.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint. Think about the footnote and why it is there. Then look at requirements for chi-square test. Also, look at the actual crosstabs to try to figure out what is going on and how the problem can be changed.